# How do I return similar results from a fulltextsqlquery search that are similar to what a keyword search provides?

Tags: fulltextsqlquery, search, 2007

I've set up the crawl to index pages based on rendered output, but now in the SELECT statement for the query, what column name can I use in the where clause?

By using a keyword search, I get results in the hithighlightedsummary column even though the title and description for the page would not contain the searched for string.  I've looked at all the other columns returned and none of them would work in the FullTextSqlQuery statement.

I'd like to use the FullTextSqlQuery instead of the Keyword search in order to provide wildcard searching by using the "like" clause.

I would love to be able to use the SELECT * syntax in order to see what is available, but this isn't possible. (I know why not.)

Answer (score 2):

Theres lots of info out there on what columns you can use

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms495418(v=office.12).aspx

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/03/06/how-to-use-the-moss-enterprise-search-fulltextsqlquery-class.aspx

Regarding using * wildcard in query syntax see my answer here:

[Using SELECT * in FullTextSqlQuery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/993/using-select-in-fulltextsqlquery)

> AFAIK you have to specifically mention
>   the columns you want.
>
> In the SQL query, you are allowed to
>   use the asterisk (*) to specify that
>   all columns in a table are to be
>   returned. However, no defined and
>   fixed set of properties applies to all
>   documents. For this reason, the SQL
>   asterisk is not permitted in the
>   [columns] setting.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms569178.aspx